# Ignore the whitespaces in string in python while searching and relacing a pattern.Dont remove the spaces for the unmatched part of original string

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string(with white spaces):
str= ‘int    a,        b,        c;’

Now I want to search a substring in the string replace by another string ignoring white space(original should have the spaces for unmatched pattern)
Old_substring:  ‘b,c;’
New_substring: ‘b,c  ,d;’

Result needed is: str= ‘int    a,        b,c  ,d;’